# npm install of private dependencies does not work but clone does

Tags: node.js, git, github, npm, git-clone

I have 3 private dependencies in my package.json. When i run npm install i get the errors. PLEASE NOTE THAT WHEN I DO CLONE OF THE SAME THEN IT CLONES ONLY NPM INSTALL DOES NOT WORK

```
Cloning into bare repository  
Permission denied (publickey). 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository. 
Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

The entire log is present below.

There are few similar issues related but none of them provide a solution in my scenario. Initially i thought it was nodejs and npm version issues so i updated them by running windows nodejs.msi and currently the version is as shown in the image. 
[image]

The contents of my package.json is as below: (most of it is removed, just the important private dependencies are mentioned)

```
  "dependencies": {
    "private-dep2": "git+ssh://git@github.comp.com:reph/private-dep2.git#v0.3.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ember-cli": "0.2.5",
    "ember-cli-app-version": "0.3.3",    
    "tough-cookie": "^0.12.1",
    "private-dep3": "git+ssh://git@github.comp.com:reph/private-dep3.git#v0.3.5",
    "private-dep1": "git+ssh://git@github.comp.com:reph/private-dep1.git#v0.7.5"
  }
```

The entire logs is as below:

```
PS C:\DDrive\Projects\p-ceck> npm cache clean
PS C:\DDrive\Projects\p-ceck>
PS C:\DDrive\Projects\p-ceck>
PS C:\DDrive\Projects\p-ceck> bower cache clean
PS C:\DDrive\Projects\p-ceck>
PS C:\DDrive\Projects\p-ceck>
PS C:\DDrive\Projects\p-ceck>
PS C:\DDrive\Projects\p-ceck> npm install
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/user_name/.ssh/id_rsa': Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/user_name/.ssh/id_rsa': Enter passphrase for key|'/c/Users/user_name/.ssh/id_rsa': |
/nter passphrase for key '/c/Users/user_name/.ssh/id_rsa': /
-nter passphrase for key '/c/Users/user_name/.ssh/id_rsa': -
/nter passphrase for key '/c/Users/user_name/.ssh/id_rsa': \
|nter passphrase for key '/c/Users/user_name/.ssh/id_rsa': -
//ter passphrase for key '/c/Users/user_name/.ssh/id_rsa': /
-nter passphrase for key '/c/Users/user_name/.ssh/id_rsa': -
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror ssh://git@github.comp.com/reph/private-dep3.git C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\ssh-git-github-comp-com-reph-private-dep3-git-bf7ad496: Cloning into bare repository 'C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\ssh-git-github-comp-com-reph-private-dep3-git-bf7ad496'...
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror ssh://git@github.comp.com/reph/private-dep3.git C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\ssh-git-github-comp-com-reph-private-dep3-git-bf7ad496: Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror ssh://git@github.comp.com/reph/private-dep3.git C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\ssh-git-github-comp-com-reph-private-dep3-git-bf7ad496: fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror ssh://git@github.comp.com/reph/private-dep3.git C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\ssh-git-github-comp-com-reph-private-dep3-git-bf7ad496:
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror ssh://git@github.comp.com/reph/private-dep3.git C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\ssh-git-github-comp-com-reph-private-dep3-git-bf7ad496: Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror ssh://git@github.comp.com/reph/private-dep3.git C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\ssh-git-github-comp-com-reph-private-dep3-git-bf7ad496: and the repository exists.
/
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror ssh://git@github.comp.com/reph/private-dep1.git C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\ssh-git-github-comp-com-reph-private-dep1-git-82b6a6b3: Cloning into bare repository 'C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\ssh-git-github-comp-com-reph-private-dep1-git-82b6a6b3'...
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror ssh://git@github.comp.com/reph/private-dep1.git C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\ssh-git-github-comp-com-reph-private-dep1-git-82b6a6b3: Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror ssh://git@github.comp.com/reph/private-dep1.git C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\ssh-git-github-comp-com-reph-private-dep1-git-82b6a6b3: fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror ssh://git@github.comp.com/reph/private-dep1.git C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\ssh-git-github-comp-com-reph-private-dep1-git-82b6a6b3:
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror ssh://git@github.comp.com/reph/private-dep1.git C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\ssh-git-github-comp-com-reph-private-dep1-git-82b6a6b3: Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror ssh://git@github.comp.com/reph/private-dep1.git C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\ssh-git-github-comp-com-reph-private-dep1-git-82b6a6b3: and the repository exists.
/
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror ssh://git@github.comp.com/reph/private-dep2.git C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\ssh-git-github-comp-com-reph-private-dep2-git-426ffed6: Cloning into bare repository 'C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\ssh-git-github-comp-com-reph-private-dep2-git-426ffed6'...
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror ssh://git@github.comp.com/reph/private-dep2.git C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\ssh-git-github-comp-com-reph-private-dep2-git-426ffed6: Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror ssh://git@github.comp.com/reph/private-dep2.git C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\ssh-git-github-comp-com-reph-private-dep2-git-426ffed6: fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror ssh://git@github.comp.com/reph/private-dep2.git C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\ssh-git-github-comp-com-reph-private-dep2-git-426ffed6:
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror ssh://git@github.comp.com/reph/private-dep2.git C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\ssh-git-github-comp-com-reph-private-dep2-git-426ffed6: Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror ssh://git@github.comp.com/reph/private-dep2.git C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\ssh-git-github-comp-com-reph-private-dep2-git-426ffed6: and the repository exists.

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.12.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1
npm ERR! code 128

npm ERR! Command failed: git -c core.longpaths=true clone --template=C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror ssh://git@github.comp.com/reph/private-dep3.git C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\ssh-git-github-comp-com-reph-private-dep3-git-bf7ad496
npm ERR! Cloning into bare repository 'C:\Users\user_name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\ssh-git-github-comp-com-reph-private-dep3-git-bf7ad496'...
npm ERR! Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\DDrive\Projects\p-ceck\npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. I ended up setting up ssh keys for my machine and npm was able to install with no problems.

[How to set up ssh keys for github.com](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/#platform-windows)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that already has an SSH key set up with Github, the solution for me was to test my Github SSH account by entering `ssh -T git@github.com` into my terminal. That prompted me for my passphrase, which I entered and now NPM is working again. If you forgot your SSH passphrase, you may be able to recover it in the Keychain Access tool by searching for `ssh`.